# Once I implement friendly_id, how do I get all actions to play nicely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, friendly-id

I have implemented friendly_id on my `PostsController`.

This is how my `PostsController` looks:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])

      # If an old id or a numeric id was used to find the record, then
      # the request path will not match the post_path, and we should do
      # a 301 redirect that uses the current friendly id.

      if request.path != post_path(@post)
          return redirect_to @post, :status => :moved_permanently
      end
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:status, :title, :photo, :file, :body, :parent_id)
    end
end
```

There are a few things happening here.

The redirect code that checks for legacy URLs and does a 301 redirect interferes with the other actions of the controller - e.g. `edit`, as can be seen here:

```
      if request.path != post_path(@post)
          return redirect_to @post, :status => :moved_permanently
      end
```

When I try to edit a post, this is what happens:

```
Started GET "/pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-02 04:46:49 -0500
Processing by PostsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke"}
  Post Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."slug" = 'pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke'  ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke
Filter chain halted as :set_post rendered or redirected
Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Also, another issue that comes up is that I have the `ancestry` gem installed. Whenever I try to create a child post, by using a URL similar to this: `http://localhost:3000/new?parent_id=pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke`

This is the error generated:

```
Started GET "/new?parent_id=pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-02 04:47:52 -0500
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"parent_id"=>"pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 35ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Post with 'id'=pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke:

() app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:19:in `new'
```

That line 19 is the `new` action in the `PostsController`...i.e.:

```
@post = Post.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
```

Both issues are connected to the `friendly_id` implementation.

How do I solve both of these issues once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Friendly_id**

First and foremost, you have to appreciate that `friendly_id` isn't such a big deal.

It works by [changing your `.find` ActiveRecord method](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb#L18), as well as giving you the ability to use the route helpers with your `slugs`.

This means any confusion you have shouldn't really be about `friendly_id` - it should be more to do with your system if anything (if you have it set up correctly, friendly_id shouldn't have to feature in any of your calls etc)

---

**Fix**

There are several issues you need to consider:

> 1. Redirect
> 2. ID

Firstly, don't handle your redirect in your controller.

I believe I answered a question to you previously - you need to handle the redirect in the *routes* part of your application. Why? That's where the *routing* occurs.

Trying to handle the redirect in the controller goes against [MVC principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (IMO) - you'll be better handling the redirect as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts, path: ''
get 'posts/:id' => redirect("/%{id}")

#get '/:id', to: 'posts#show' -> NOT NEEDED. Will be covered by the resources directive
#get 'posts/:id', to: 'posts#show' -> NOT NEEDED. Will be covered by redirect

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :slug, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will fix all your problems.

If you use the friendly_id `finders` module, you don't need to distinguish any custom `:friendly_id` params or anything. It will just ping your database for the `id` and `slug` - no big deal.

You're overcomplicating this massively - you just need to redirect any `/posts/***` to `/:id` (which will go to the `posts` controller anyway). This way, your `:id` will still be handled in the same way as it would *without* the `friendly_id` integration

Comment: You did answer another question...so thank you :) This does work perfectly. I wasn't using the `:finders` module for `:friendly_id` so that could also have been contributing to the fact that regular `.find(params[:id])` wasn't working.

Comment: I guess the one behavior that I notice that is a bit odd, is if I go to `post/26/` in my app it doesn't redirect to the `friendly_id` URL. It just stays at `/26/`....whereas the old redirect functionality in the controller did redirect that fully to the long URL. How can I do that with a redirect in my `routes.rb`?

Comment: The redirect is for `/posts/`, right? Surely that would mean you'd be better using `/posts/26`?

Comment: What I am saying is, `friendly_id` converts all ugly URLs (e.g. `posts/26/` to more SEO & human friendly URLs (e.g. `posts/some-awesome-post-title`). However, with the current redirect it doesn't redirect/mask the URL if someone types in /26/ it just stays at /26/ rather than redirecting to `some-awesome-post-title` which is what that little `if` method in my `posts_controller` did. In other words, the current redirect in the `routes.rb` file does not fully replace the functionality of the redirect in my controller - when I would like it to.